# How Can I Store method calls into an Array in Ruby instead of calling them

Tags: ruby

I am working on a project where in the test suite we are calling a bunch of methods within a class
We have to keep these in, but they stop the programme when they are called, so as a work around I am trying to find a way to push method calls into an array, so I can deal with them later.

The problem is kind of similar to this at this stage:

```
def hello(greeting)
  puts greeting
end

class Dog
  hello "Cat"
  hello "Bear"
  hello "Snake"
  hello "Pig"
  hello "Cow"
  hello "Wolf"
  hello "Lion"

end
```

The question is: Is there some way I can STORE those method calls into an array, to be executed later?

Edit:

```
class Dog
  assert 1 + 1 =2

end
```

this is closer the the code I am working with, the classes contain asserts which stop the programme when they fail. I have to keep the class the same in the test suite, so I cannot remove these asserts- but If I want to test for the same thing in the test suite, I cannot trigger them. This is why I want to find a way to iterate through the class and push method calls to an array- to execute them *after* the test suite has run. I hope that's a bit clearer

I think there is a misunderstanding. The CLASS cannot change. I am trying to iterate through a class to dynamically iterate through the instances of a method is already calls.

Can I iterate Through the Dog Class, and write a method for each hello?

Comment: "but they stop the programme when they are called"
Can you explain more about this? Stop how? an error?

Comment: You can use Procs or lambdas to store closures in an Array, but your posted code sample doesn't appear to justify the complexity of doing that. It would probably be better to store either the results or the inputs.

Comment: The class is in our test suite, and the "hello" method, is actually an assert, so the difficultly i'm facing is using the assert, but trying to delay it while writing tests. I am required to keep the asserts in the body of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find a way to iterate through the class and push method calls to an array- to execute them after the test suite has run.

If you want to defer a method call, you can indeed store it in an array. You can then use `#send` to call it whenever you like. Here's an example:

```
def a
  puts 'Called a'
end

def b
  puts 'Called b'
end

def c
  puts 'Called c'
end

def d
  puts 'Called d'
end

def my_test
  methods = []
  # assert this, assert that, and
  # if I need to call method a, then
  methods << :a
  # and so on...
  methods << :b
  methods << :c
  methods << :d
end

# Now, to call the methods in the array:

my_test.each { |method| send method }
```

One important point is that method names are stored internally in Ruby as symbols, so every time you `def` a method, the method name gets stored as a symbol. Then, you can use the symbol with `#send` to call the method. If you tinker with this idea a bit you should get what you want.

#### Edit: Take Two

I took another look at your problem, and I believe I have a better handle on it. You still need to use `#send`, but there's more to it.

You have a number of direct calls to the `hello` method in your class, which makes some things difficult. If you add this line:

```
Dog
```

to your code, you will get a list of all the animals, one by one.

If, instead, you want to store the method calls to an array to call later, you have to find a place to put the array. This is difficult:

- You can't alter the `Dog` class, so you can't put it there.
- You can't put it in the `hello` method, because it won't keep its values between calls.
- You can't put it in another class and then instantiate it, because you can't then pass the instance into `hello`; since `hello` is getting called from the class and you're not allowed to change the class, you can't modify those calls to pass in the instance.

After a bit of tinkering, I came up with a solution. What you need is a class that does the work for you (appropriately named `DogWalker` here), instantiated as a singleton instance:

```
require 'singleton'

def hello(method)
  DogWalker.instance.add_method(method)
end

class DogWalker
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @methods = []
  end

  def add_method(method)
    @methods << method.downcase.to_sym
  end

  def call_methods
    @methods.each do |m| 
      self.respond_to?(m) ? send(m) : send(:etc)
    end
  end

  def cat
    puts 'called Cat'
  end

  def bear
    puts 'called Bear'
  end

  def snake
    puts 'called Snake'
  end

  def pig
    puts 'called Pig'
  end

  def etc
    puts 'called one of the others'
  end
end

class Dog
  hello "Cat"
  hello "Bear"
  hello "Snake"
  hello "Pig"
  hello "Cow"
  hello "Wolf"
  hello "Lion"
end

Dog

DogWalker.instance.call_methods
```

To do this, you need to require the `singleton` module. This module exposes an `::instance` method, which essentially says "If there is an instance of this class already out there, return it. Otherwise, create a new one."

The `DogWalker` class is exposed as a singleton instance, by calling `DogWalker::instance` everywhere we reference it. That way, we're always working with the same instance of `DogWalker`.

We first run `Dog`, which calls the `hello` method in your `Dog` class several times. `hello` calls `DogWalker.instance.add_method`, which (creates an instance of `DogWalker` the first and only the first time that `#instance` is called, and) pushes the method symbol onto the `@methods` array.

This variable is preserved between method calls to `hello`; since we're using the `instance` method, we keep working with the same instance of `DogWalker`. (This way, we don't have to put `DogWalker.new` inside the `hello` method, or put it outside the `hello` method and pass it in. The first would keep re-initializing `@methods`, and we aren't allowed to do the second.)

When we're all done, calling the `DogWalker` instance's `call_methods` method runs all the methods one by one (I just abbreviated with `etc` in the example).

So, this lets you run your `Dog` class and defer calling all those methods until after the `Dog` class is done.

Direct method calls in a class are a pretty horrible way to design things, but as you say, your hands are tied, and you ought to be able to modify this to get your job done.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty useful, the issue I am having though is that I am trying to iterate through the class as is, and store the method calls, so if the method is called 4 times, it gets pushed 4 times, if 5 times, then 5 methods get stored.

Comment: @LouisRaymond Reading between the lines a bit, I think I figured out what your problem is, and put up what I think is a solution for you.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @LouisRaymond You're welcome. I've never found an occasion to use 'singleton' before, so I learned something too. Bizarre code has its purposes, I guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to *the question you asked* is:

```rb
def hello(greeting)
  puts greeting
end
hello_targets = %w[Cat Bear Snake Pig Cow Wolf Lion]

lazy_greetings = hello_targets.map do |target|
  -> { hello(target) }
end


# later, whenever you want
lazy_greetings[4].call # puts 'Cow'

lazy_greetings.each(&:call)
# Cat
# Bear
# Snake
# Pig
# Cow
# Wolf
# Lion
```

However, I feel like what you really want isn't encapsulated in the question you've asked.

For example, given the example you've posted, there's not a good reason to do it as I've posted above. The code below is simpler and does the same thing.

```rb
hello_targets = %w[Cat Bear Snake Pig Cow Wolf Lion]


# later, whenever you want
hello(args[4]) # puts 'Cow'

hello_targets.each { |target| hello(target) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just creating another method that does the desired calls, and just call that method when neccesary? Something like this:

```
def hello(greeting)
  puts greeting
end

class Dog
  def self.sayHello()
    hello "Cat"
    hello "Bear"
    hello "Snake"
    hello "Pig"
    hello "Cow"
    hello "Wolf"
    hello "Lion"
  end
end

# later 

Dog.sayHello()
```

Comment: `SyntaxError`, and when you fix that, `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Because, as the OP mentions, he isn't allowed to alter the `Dog` class: "I have to keep the class the same in the test suite."